# Visual Explain Not working in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, explain

Is there some trick to getting the Visual Explain feature to work in MySQL Workbench?

I am running version 6.3.6 on Windows 7.
I've tried simple queries with just one join. I've tried it with complex queries with 12 Joins.
I've tried it with MySQL 5.5 and 5.7.

But every time I just get `Explain Data Not Available For Statement`

I've looked on the Bugs for MySQL Workbench > Visual Explain, but there is no recent bugs, making me think it is something I am doing.
But I can't see what. Does anyone have some suggestions?

Comment: [MySQL Workbench forum](http://forums.mysql.com/list.php?152) is often monitored by the developers.

Comment: OK cheers, I'll try there.

Answer (score 5):

The user raising this question got an answer in the [MySQL Workbench Forum](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?152,644169,644214#msg-644214):

> Visual Explain is only available if your server supports the JSON explain output (MySQL 5.6.5 or newer).

The reason VISUAL EXPLAIN didn't work for the user with 5.7, was the query being already prepended with `explain` at input time. Workbench transformed this into `explain explain format=json` - what wouldn't work.